# scrapy pagination without href

Tags: pagination, scrapy

I created a spider that takes the information from the table below, but I can not change to the previous table because it does not have "href", how do I?

https://br.soccerway.com/teams/italy/as-roma/1241/

[image: data that I want]

previous button without href

```
<a rel="previous" class="previous " id="page_team_1_block_team_matches_summary_7_previous">« anterior</a>
```

[image: html of the "previous" button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at network inspector in your browser you can see an XHR request being made when you click next button:
[image]

That request return json response with html changes:

[image]

You need to reverse engineer how your page generated this url (from the first image):

https://br.soccerway.com/a/block_team_matches_summary?block_id=page_team_1_block_team_matches_summary_7&callback_params=%7B%22page%22%3A0%2C%22bookmaker_urls%22%3A%7B%2213%22%3A%5B%7B%22link%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bet365.com%2Fhome%2F%3Faffiliate%3D365_371546%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Bet%20365%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%22block_service_id%22%3A%22team_summary_block_teammatchessummary%22%2C%22team_id%22%3A1241%2C%22competition_id%22%3A0%2C%22filter%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22new_design%22%3Afalse%7D&action=changePage&params=%7B%22page%22%3A1%7D

And then you can use that to retrieve following pages.